# Yii Activerecord doesn't join with nested relation

Tags: php, yii

I have defined the following criteria in Yii, and tries to use it to fetch an array of customers.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
        "condition"=>"hidden = 0".(Yii::app()->user->GetState('is_admin') ? "" : " AND franchisesMunicipalities.franchise_id=".Yii::app()->user->getState('fid')),
        "with" => array('municipality','municipality.franchisesMunicipalities')
));
$customers = Customers::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

This (i thought) should result in that Yii joined the table Customers with the table Municipalities, and then in the same query join the table Municipalities with the table Franchises_Municipalities. However it doesn't work since it doesn't join franchisesMunicipalities.

The resulting query is this

```
SELECT `t`.`id`                   AS `t0_c0`, 
   `t`.`municipality_id`      AS `t0_c1`, 
   `t`.`personal_code_number` AS `t0_c2`, 
   `t`.`name`                 AS `t0_c3`, 
   `t`.`adress`               AS `t0_c4`, 
   `t`.`zip`                  AS `t0_c5`, 
   `t`.`phone`                AS `t0_c6`, 
   `t`.`mobile`               AS `t0_c7`, 
   `t`.`email`                AS `t0_c8`, 
   `t`.`hidden`               AS `t0_c9`, 
   `municipality`.`id`        AS `t1_c0`, 
   `municipality`.`county_id` AS `t1_c1`, 
   `municipality`.`name`      AS `t1_c2` 
FROM   `customers` `t` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `municipalities` `municipality` 
                ON ( `t`.`municipality_id` = `municipality`.`id` ) 
WHERE  ( hidden = 0 
     AND municipality.franchisesmunicipalities.franchise_id = 7 ) 
LIMIT  30
```

As you can see it only joins on one relation. The relations in the model should be correctly defined, since i am able to use them in other contexts.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I don't know the framework, but it looks like it thinks `municipality.franchisesMunicipalities` is a table name. Perhaps look at the docs for the `with` clause?

Comment: The with clause should be correct, if it's incorrect Yii is telling me that, and doesn't even try to query the DB.

Comment: Well `municipality.franchisesmunicipalities.franchise_id` doesn't look very correct to me, and that would seem to relate directly to your `"with"` condition. But like I say, I've not used Yii, so it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah i don't think that is correct either, but that isn't the main problem. The problem is that it doesn't join at all.

Comment: `franchisesMunicipalities` is declared as a relation on your `Municipalities` model?

Comment: Yes it is, otherwise Yii would let me know...

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail I believe you should be doing it this way:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
        "condition"=>"hidden = 0".(Yii::app()->user->GetState('is_admin') ? "" : " AND franchisesMunicipalities.franchise_id=".Yii::app()->user->getState('fid'))
));
$customers = Customers::model()->with('municipality','municipality.franchisesMunicipalities')->findAll($criteria);
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: This seems to be equivalent with my code above, since it produces the same SQL-query. The problem still remains the same, it doesn't join the table `franchisesmunicipalities`.

Comment: The relation in Customers
`'municipality' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Municipalities', 'municipality_id')`
The relation in Municipalities
`'franchisesMunicipalities' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FranchiseMunicipalities', 'municipality_id')`

Comment: Not sure I'll try setting up a similar situation and see if I have the same issue. Just wondering what version of Yii are you using?